# Field in View linked to another View

Tags: views

I created View "Places" consisting of 3 fields (image,date and title) filtered by content type.

This is to create a page showing thumbnails.

I created another view "Gallery" showing images and I need this View to be linked to the corresponding thumbnail image.

Any idea how i can achieve this?
Thanks to everyone...

Comment: Do you wan't the images in the `Gallery` view linking to the thumbnail in your `Places` view?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You could try making the **path** for each display some kind of hierarchy and using **Menu tab** as the menu Page settings in order to display both views next to each other in the primary tabs of a page.

**Example paths**

```
mypath/view1 // Display 1
mypath/view2 // Display 2
```

**Solution 2**

Add a header or footer to the view in **Basic settings** and include the link to the other view.

More info on [Drupal Menu system](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/6).

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how can I make it so that clicking on any of the images in the *Places* View take the user to the *Gallery* view, then this is just a matter of applying Rewrite Results in the configuration for the image view. Check the 'Output this field as a link' box and then put in the fixed path to the gallery. If you want to pass a parameter to the gallery then this is possible by using the replacement patterns available in Rewrite Results.

If this answer is way off base, you might need to fill out your question a little.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out by using Link image field instead of just image field in my content type and it works.

Comment: But for the future...Obliquely, I was trying the rewrite result before and I don't know how to use it properly because I have more thumbnails (different ones) and need to link them to many galeries. What replacement pattern should I use? I've got very limited choice... or should I apply any sort of relationship beforehand? Thanks...