# Link to Existing View from another view

Tags: views

Im trying to create a view that should have a field which links to a pre-existing view (And Permissioned appropriately). Ive looked into various modules and field options but cannot find it (Newbie to Drupal!).

Basically, I have a view(called, Recipe_Filter) where I have some filters for selecting recipes based on various conditions. I have another view where I show recipes for a particular user and also want to create an "Edit" link that points to Recipe_filter. The problem is that I dont want normal users to see the "Edit" link and only certain roles to be able to view this.

I tried suggestions like the one in [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65056/field-in-view-linked-to-another-view) but if I do as in that link, I see a "Edit" link and clicking on it shows a "You are not authorized  to access this page" text. I would like to disable the Edit Link if the user doesnt have access.

Are there modules that will allow a link to an existing view and permission it (like how the standard "Edit to content" or "View to content" works). Any help or pointers would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using Views PHP Using some custom PHP to show the "link" only if the user has permission. Not sure if thats the most elegant way.

I would like to know if there is a better approach to solving this. Thanks!